# duplicate messages in socket.io, socket.on

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, backend

I'm making a chat application with a backend in node.js and using sockets for real time updates. When I send the message by clicking on the button where I have put the event it brings duplicate messages, first one then two and so on.

javascript do html:

```
const button = document.getElementById("btn")
const chat = document.getElementById("chat")
const socket = io()

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    const message = document.getElementById("message")
    socket.emit("send", message.value)
    socket.on("sends", (dados)=>{
        showMessage(dados)
        console.log(socket)
    })
})

function showMessage(mensagem){
    chat.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<p><strong>User: </strong>${mensagem}</p>`) 
}
```

server

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const http = require("http")
const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = require("socket.io")(server)
app.use(express.static("public"))

io.on("connection", (socket)=>{ 
    console.log(socket.id)
    socket.on("send", (data)=>{
        socket.emit("sends", data)
    })
})
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000)
```

I've been trying to solve it for hours and I can't figure out what is the issue.

Comment: could you try removing the `console.log(socket)` socket log from client code?

Comment: I've tried it, but it's still the same behavior, at first I also thought it was that, but it wasn't